# Colour Picker Button

Tags: html, reactjs

I was thinking of a color picker button like Google Keep where I can click on the button and a few colors pop up and i can choose between the colors. How could I implement it into my own website

Comment: There's an HTML5 color picker that might spare you a lot of effort: [`<input type="color">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)

Comment: I feel the think the color picker gives too many options and from a user standpoint it might be too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the built in color picker?

```
<input type="color">
```

[Learn More](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_color.asp)

Comment: I feel the think the color picker gives too many options and from a user standpoint it might be too much